# BottomTab.Screen sometimes doesn't work on real devices

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i'm using react-native with reactnativation

BottomTab.Screen touches well in the emulator, but when testing with a real device, somethime Touch works fine but sometime second BottomTab cannot be touched

The second bottomtab is  component={SecondTab}

this is my bottomTab  (problem is second bottomtab)

[image]

this is my code

```
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

    const KakaoNavigator = () => {
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Kakao"
            component={Kakao}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Nickname"
            component={Nickname}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    };

    const FirstTab = () => {
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Vieww"
            component={Vieww}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Main"
            component={Main}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Food"
            component={Food}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
        
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    };

    const SecondTab = () => {
      return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Upload"
            component={Upload}
            options={{
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      );
    };


    const MainTabs = () => {
      return (
        <BottomTab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{showLabel: false}}>
          <BottomTab.Screen
            name="FirstTab"
            component={FirstTab}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({color, focused}) => (
                <Image
                  source={
                    focused
                      ? require('../Assets/Images/Tabs/ic_home.png')
                      : require('..//Assets/Images/Tabs/ic_home_outline.png')
                  }
                />
              ),
            }}
          />

          <BottomTab.Screen
            name="SecondTab"
            component={SecondTab}
            options={{
              tabBarIcon: ({color, focused}) => (
                <Image
                  source={
                    focused
                      ? require('..//Assets/Images/Tabs/ic_add.png')
                      : require('..//Assets/Images/Tabs/ic_add_outline.png')
                  }
                />
              ),
            }}
          />
        </BottomTab.Navigator>
      );
    };

    export default () => {
      const {me} = useSelector((state) => state.user);

      return (
        <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
          {me && me.nickname ? <MainTabs /> : <KakaoNavigator />}
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Turning "Use network-provided time" in the Date & Time settings off and on fixes the issue I think

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad oh from where:)??